# VBA - Selection.Formula does not return everything

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

Say I have a very long formula in one of my cells in Excel:

> =IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z 01",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   02",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   03",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   04",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   05",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   06",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   07",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   08",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   09",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   10",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   11",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   12",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   13",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   14","no" ))))))))))))))

Now when I call the following VBA sub

```
Private Sub Get_Formula()
    MsgBox Selection.Formula
End Sub
```

then I don't receive the full formula, but only

> =IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z 01",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   02",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   03",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   04",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   05",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   06",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   07",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   08",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   09",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   10",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   11",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   12",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   13", IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V

How can I obtain the full formula?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306859/msgbox-not-big-enough-for-text It's kind of redundant though, it's not like you'll be able  to do anything with it anyway.

Comment: 1024 chars, I would take a "guess" that that is the limit for message length in a messagebox. I would look to shrinking the formula down. I am a little confused by it though as the criteria is the same on every if which means it will always be either A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z 13 or no. Even then you could have an IF to work out the prefix (A-Z) or Blank as that is static then an if to work out the suffix 01 - 13 or No it would be MUCH shorter

Comment: How about showing the REAL formula so we can help you reduce it? BTW, that truncated formula happens to be exactly 1024 characters long. When you see numbers like 255, 1024, 16384, etc) you should recognize them as a clue to an internal limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *"prompt"* parameter of the MsgBox function has a maximum length approximately 1024 characters, depending on the width of the characters used. ([see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251821(v=office.15).aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB6fe.png))

You can obtain the entire formula by printing it in the Visual Basic immediate window with this code:

```
Sub Get_Formula()
    Rem Opens Immediate Window and Clears it
    SendKeys "^g^a{DEL}": Stop

    With ActiveCell
        Debug.Print vbLf; vbLf; String(131, "*")
        Debug.Print "Formula in Wbk\Wsh\Cell: "; .Parent.Parent.Name; " \ "; .Parent.Name; " \ "; .Address(0, 0)
        Debug.Print ActiveCell.Formula
        Debug.Print vbLf; String(131, "*"); vbLf
    End With
    SendKeys "^g^{HOME}" ': Stop
End Sub
```

Additionally, I see some inconsistencies in the formula but I guess it just a bogus formula used to explain the problem with the MsgBox function.
This long formulas are difficult to read, may I suggest to use the *Alt+Enter* keys combined to start a new line in the same cell thus breaking your formula in several lines (see picture below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I put your rather large formula in **A1**  Then in **A2** thru **A15** I inserted:

```
=MID(A$1,76*(ROW()-2)+1,75)
```

and I ran this macro:

```
Sub dural2()
  With Range("A1")
    .Formula = "'" & .Formula
  End With

  ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(332.25, 62.25, 242.25, 120).Select
    s = Selection.Name
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(s).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "A2:A15"
        .LinkedCell = "$Z$1"
        .MultiSelect = xlNone
        .Display3DShading = True
    End With
End Sub
```

and got this somewhat ugly result:

[image]

**I am not proposing this as a practical solution.**  Just a demo that the *ListBox* with a scroll bar can display enough characters